# Have DKIM and domain authorization/authentication setup but mail is still sent to spam. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

As the title states I have everything setup for my domain and sender email(s) as far as authorization and authentication in Amazon SES. Still, any emails sent from my domain are still being sent as spam. I should note the site was launched a few days ago. I've read that email rep plays a factor but didn't think that **every** email would still be marked spam despite my configuration. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Who's the email provider where it's getting sent to spam?  Self hosted?  Google?  ZOHO?  Microsoft?

Comment: Yahoo and MS. Surprisingly AOL is fine. Gmail works too.

Comment: If MS already blacklisted you once as spam, you will need to go and find your source IP and check your logs to see if they're actually blocking your messages with their rejection system.  As for Yahoo, their systems are poor quality for updating 'reputation', so short of whitelisting I'm not sure you'll protect yourself there.  Do you also have SPF and DMARC set up?

Comment: I have SPF but not DMARC. Do you think that'll help a little more? As far as finding then source IP for MS, is that something you're able to do on SES. I'm only shown a few graphs on my sending statistics page. No details as far as who or statuses of delivered messages like Sendgrid provides.

Comment: Not sure, you could probably find the origin IP by looking in the raw headers of one of the other received ends for the origin IP address of the messages and then compare them.  I was asking about DMARC because sometimes that can cause problems, not because it should be implemented.  If Microsoft continues to blacklist your messages you may need to reach out to them, as for Yahoo, your guess is as good as mine why they still have you going to spam.

Answer (score 0):

You say that Microsoft is marking your email as spam, so you should be able to find out why, even if it's not easy to fix it.

If you look at the SMTP headers of an email received on a microsoft service, they include lots of diagnostic headers that help you understand the spam score.

Here's a link to the documentation from Microsoft Office 365.  Even if you're using a different Microsoft product, I assume the headers would be the same or  similar.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/anti-spam-message-headers

This will allow you to work out if it's IP reputation or content heuristics for example.

As you say, if some providers such as Gmail are okay with your email, it shouldn't be a fundamental problem such as your SPF being configured incorrect, it will be something subjective such as IP reputation.